# mosquitto denied access by tcpd

Tags: mosquitto, libmosquitto

I used mosquitto as MQTT broker, and it seems if connection number is more than 1000, the below log printed. Anybody know something about this?

`1470896904: Client connection from 111.7.170.177 denied access by tcpd.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel your process(mosquitto) have hit the maximum number of open file descriptors limit. Check your max open files by `ulimit -n`. Then increase the limit to max number of connections expected by you. E.g. For 10k connection it would be `ulimit -n 10000`

A note on ulimit([1](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)). It is only set for the current terminal and for persistent changes you will need to edit config files as per your Linux flavor( */etc/security/limits.conf* + */etc/pam.d/common-session** on Ubuntu ).

Comment: The max open files number is 1000000, much larger than connection number.

Comment: @FengChris Check the user account with which mosquitto is run. Is it logged in user or user in mosquitto.conf ? Then check limit for that user.

Comment: I used supervisor to start mosquitto and the max open files limited to 1024 by supervisor as default.  Add `minfds=1000000` in `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` can resolve this problem.

Comment: I am facing the same trouble, but this answer not solve my issue. Do you know any other change I can do to solve the problem? I am using mosquitto 1.6.3 on ubuntu 14. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There might be another reason for this error message. The same message wil be displayed in the log if a client tries to connect and access is denied by TCPD. You need to adjust hosts.allow (in my case for localhost 127.0.0.1) to connect.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer as it may not be the issue at all (doesn't sound like it). With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem using Ubuntu 14 with mosquitto 1.6.3 and I solved my issue making these changes:

Open the: /etc/init/mosquitto.conf file

Add `limit nofile 4096 4096` before `exec`;

> 4096 indicate the number of clients

`service mosquitto stop`
`service mosquitto start`

I hope help another people that have the same issue.